A pair of mappings $f, g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ and $g$ are idempotent, commute with each other and $f \times g$ is bijective
The question
The question is:
Does there exist a pair of mappings $f, g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following properties?

$f$ and $g$ are idempotent, meaning that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $f(f(n)) = f(n)$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $g(g(n)) = g(n)$

$f$ and $g$ commute, meaning that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $f(g(n)) = g(f(n))$

$f \times g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, n \mapsto (f(n), g(n))$ is a bijection


An equivalent question is the following:
Does there exist a bijective mapping $h: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that is associative, meaning that $\forall n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$: $h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3) = h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3))$?
The proof that the questions are equivalent
Here is how to construct $h$ given $f$ and $g$: Define another mapping $i: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, n \mapsto (f(n), f(g(n)), g(g(n))) = (f(f(n)), g(f(n)), g(n))$. The two expressions for $i$ are the same because of the required properties of $f$ and $g$. Note that $i$ is bijective because $f \times g$ is bijective. Now, let $h = (f \times g)^{-1}$. Take $n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, we have
$$
i(h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3)) = (f(f(h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3))), g(f(h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3))), g(h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3))) = (f(h(n_1, n_2)), g(h(n_1, n_2)), n_3) = (n_1, n_2, n_3)
$$
and we also have
$$
i(h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3))) = (f(h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3))), f(g(h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3)))), g(g(h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3))))) = (n_1, f(h(n_2, n_3)), g(h(n_2, n_3))) = (n_1, n_2, n_3)
$$
As $i$ is bijective, we have that $h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3) = h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3))$.
Here is how to construct $f$ and $g$ given $h$: Define another mapping $j: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, (n_1, n_2, n_3) \mapsto h(h(n_1, n_2), n_3) = h(n_1, h(n_2, n_3))$. The two expressions for $j$ are the same because of the associativity of $h$. Note that $j$ is bijective because $h$ is bijective. Now, let $f = \pi_1 \circ h^{-1}$ and $g = \pi_2 \circ h^{-1}$. Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, we have
$$
j(f(n), f(g(n)), g(g(n))) = h(f(n), h(f(g(n)), g(g(n)))) = h(f(n), g(n)) = n
$$
and
$$
j(f(f(n)), g(f(n)), g(n)) = h(h(f(f(n)), g(f(n))), g(n)) = h(f(n), g(n)) = n
$$
As $j$ is bijective, we have that $f(f(n)) = f(n)$, $g(g(n)) = g(n)$ and $f(g(n)) = g(f(n))$.
The motivation
The motivation is this: Assume we are given a set $X$ and an associative binary operation $\cdot: X \times X \to X$. Consider the set $\Phi = \{\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to X\}$. We would like to endow $\Phi$ with an associative binary operation via $\cdot_{\Phi}: \Phi \times \Phi \to \Phi, (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot_{\Phi} (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_{f(n)} \cdot y_{g(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. This will be associative due to
$$
((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot_{\Phi} (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) \cdot_{\Phi} (z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_{f(n)} \cdot y_{g(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot_{\Phi} (z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = ((x_{f(f(n))} \cdot y_{g(f(n))}) \cdot z_{g(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_{f(n)} \cdot (y_{f(g(n))} \cdot z_{g(g(n))}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot_{\Phi} (y_{f(n)} \cdot z_{g(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot_{\Phi} ((y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot_{\Phi} (z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})
$$

I would appreciate suggestions on how to tag this question in the Tagging Room

this seems like it might be relevant

By writing "bijection" you are claiming in particular that $f \times g$ maps $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$?  But that's impossible: indeed if $x \in f(\mathbb N)$, say $x = f(y)$, then $f(x) = f(f(y)) = f(y) = x$.

$f$ being idempotent means the range of $f$ consists entirely of fixed points of $f$. $f\times g$ being onto implies the range of $f$ is $\Bbb N$, so $f$ can only be the identity function. Same for $g$.

Thanks. Would you consider writing your comments up as an answer?
